# localToWorld weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, three.js

Good evening!

In my project I'm creating a TextMesh from a font geometry and put into a pivot empty object. I need to get the world coordinates of every vertex of the TextMesh because I need to work with them to do some transformations of the text (custom bending etc...).

Here's the code:

```
var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
pivot.add(textMesh);

pivot.position.set(x, y, z);
pivot.rotation.set(roll, pitch, yaw);
scene.add(pivot);

pivot.updateMatrixWorld(true);
for(var i = 0; i < textMesh.geometry.vertices.length; i++)
{
    var worldCoords = textMesh.localToWorld(textMesh.geometry.vertices[i]);
}
```

What happens is that my textMesh has its position changed by the "localToWorld" function, which I didn't expect.
Is there a way to get the world location of each vertex of the mesh without making the mesh move?
What am I doing wrong?
Is there an easier way to do a bending of a text mesh along a cylinder? I have already checked MOD3 and such and couldn't find anything which works with my setup so I was trying to do it myself.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var worldCoords = textMesh.localToWorld(textMesh.geometry.vertices[i].clone());
```

or, if you want to re-use `worldCoords`:

```
var worldCoords = new THREE.Vector3();
textMesh.localToWorld(worldCoords.copy(textMesh.geometry.vertices[i]));
```

Comment: The important take-away here is that `localToWorld` (and `worldToLocal`) is (are) destructive to the data passed to it. If you want to keep your data as-is, but just get the values, copy/clone your original `Vector3`, and then pass the copy into `localToWorld`/`worldToLocal`.

Comment: @TheJim01 Correct. But seems, that it's not obvious for users, from the phrase _"**Converts** the vector from local space to world space. "_ in the documentation about [`THREE.Object3D()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D). And who cares about to read this doc. :)